# Python: Dynamically access type annotation of a property

Tags: python

Given the following class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, test_prop: str):
        self.__test_prop = test_prop
    @property
    def test_prop(self) -> str:
        return self.__test_prop
```

How can I dynamically access the type annotation of `test_prop` either from the class or an instance?

The following does not work:

```
t1 = Test('a')
import inspect
inspect.signature(t1.test_prop)
# TypeError: 'a' is not a callable object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the `property` object itself, without doing the dynamic lookup.  The `inspect` module has a function, [`inspect.getattr_static`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getattr_static) for that. Then we can use `signature` to get the signature of the `fget` attribute of that object. That's where `property` objects store the function they use to do the dynamic lookup.

```
from inspect import getattr_static, signature

print(signature(getattr_static(t1, 'test_prop').fget))
# (self) -> str
```

The other two functions of a property are stored in the attributes `fset` and `fdel`

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't figure out how to get behind the descriptor.